# How to use a target's property value inside a control template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

What do I need to do to the control template to have the rectangle vary with the width of the button?

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
   <Grid>
      <Polygon ... />
      <Rectangle Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" />
      <Polygon ... />
   </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<Button Template="MyButtonTemplate" Width="25" />
<Button Template="MyButtonTemplate" Width="50" />
<Button Template="MyButtonTemplate" Width="75" />
```

I don't want the rectangle to be exactly 25, 50, and 75 units wide, respectively; instead, I might want the rectangle to be 22, 47, and 72 units wide (three pixels shorter than the width of the button).

Is there a way for me to do some sort of math in XAML, or is my only resort to use a value converter such as the one listed [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/239251/MathConverter-How-to-Do-Math-in-XAML)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the width to your Grid and change the margin property of your Rectangle:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Background="DarkBlue" >
         <Polygon />
              <Rectangle Margin="1.5,0,1.5,0" Fill="Aquamarine" />
         <Polygon />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```